# BigQuery Grouping, Aggregation query question/problem

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions

I've been stuck on a problem today regarding grouping and aggregation that I haven't been able to solve.  Perhaps someone here sees what I need to do.

The query with the problem is here:

```
SELECT campaign_id,
        campaign_name,
        start_time,
        end_time,
        sum(clicks) as clicks,
        sum(impressions) as impressions,
        sum(reach) as reach,
        sum(spend) as cost,
        avg(cpc) as cpc,
        sum(PARSE_NUMERIC(a.value)) as mobile_app_install,
        FROM dataexploration-193817.marketing_data.facebook_ads_data
        JOIN UNNEST(actions) as a
        WHERE a.action_type = 'mobile_app_install' AND  start_time >= '{date_start}' AND start_time <= '{date_end}'
        group by campaign_id,campaign_name,start_time,end_time;
```

The query is leaving out all data unless there is an action type of mobile_app_install.  But if I remove that constraint, I get multiple rows for each campaign, which I also don't want.   What I want is one row, per campaign_id that sums up each value (with or without a mobile_app_install action_type but also brings me the sum of mobile_app_install.  The actions column is a RECORD type with the items "action_type" and "value".

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's preferred to put a representative sample of your data as text in the question. Saves people from having click on unknown links.

Comment: When you remove the `mobile_app_install` filter in your `where` clause, you are still grouping by `a.action_type` so you will get multiple rows, even though you aren't selecting it.

Comment: Also, please alias your tables and then add aliases to all columns - so that we can tell where each column is coming from

Comment: There is only a single table so nothing to alias.  I tried to turn this into a markup table of text but reality is, I need to show enough data for the problem set so need to leave it.  I removed the grouping.

Comment: Now that you have edited the query to remove action_type from grouping, do you still have any issue?

Comment: Yes, the original issue is that I only get the data from the rows where a.action_type = 'mobile_app_install' .  I need the SUM functions to total up all the rows for each campaign.  From my research, it seems this might be possible with a PIVOT where I can transform each action_type to a column but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: do you expect to have more than one line for the same campaign in source data (with similar or different actions in each row)?

Comment: I solved it in code by running two queries and merging the datasets.  Not optimal, but it worked.  Still hopeful to solve in a single query.

Comment: @PratikPatil if you look at the Google Sheet you will see the source data on the table and the Record column and how it is laid out.  Yes, there is a record for every day on each campaign

Answer (score 1):

The type is `array of record` and you are lateral cross joining with it, thus causing duplicates, I assume.

You can add contraints using a lateral subquery

```sql
SELECT campaign_id,
       campaign_name,
       start_time,
       end_time,
       sum(clicks) as clicks,
       sum(impressions) as impressions,
       sum(reach) as reach,
       sum(spend) as cost,
       avg(cpc) as cpc,
       sum(
         (select sum(PARSE_NUMERIC(a.value)) 
          from unnest(actions) as a 
          where action_type = 'mobile_app_install'
         )
       ) as mobile_app_install,
FROM 
   dataexploration-193817.marketing_data.facebook_ads_data t
WHERE 
   EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM unnest(actions) 
          WHERE action_type = 'mobile_app_install' )
   AND start_time >= '{date_start}' 
   AND start_time <= '{date_end}'
GROUP BY
   campaign_id, campaign_name, start_time, end_time
;
```

`unnest()` turns an array into a relation on which you can run SQL

Comment: Thanks Martin,

What becomes of "sum(PARSE_NUMERIC(a.value)) as mobile_app_install," in the original query if there is no longer a JOIN UNNEST ?

Comment: Right, let me fix that - essentially a subquery again

Comment: Thanks Martin.  This still only returns the sums for rows with action_type mobile_app_install where I need it to return sum of all rows regardless of whether it has mobile_app_install  or not.

Comment: then you should remove the EXISTS() condition